# Towers of Hanoi if big disks can go on top of small disks

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) puzzle is concerned with moving $n$ disks between three pegs so that a larger disk cannot be placed on top of a smaller disk. Based on a [(now deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67681029/solving-tower-of-ha-noi-with-disk-randomly-initiate) StackOverflow question, suppose that one can place larger disks above smaller ones.

One can represent the game state by a 3-tuple of ordered sets $(A, B, C)$.

For example, the solved state with $3$ disks is given by $([3,2,1], [], [])$:

```
1
2
3
* * *
```

Question: given an arbitrary game state, what is a minimal sequence of moves that reaches the solved state? ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096256/tower-of-hanoi-solutions-for-non-legal-initial-configuration) thread suggests that reaching the solved state is always possible).

- There is a unique solved state with all disks placed on the first peg in order (illustrated above).
- Ideally, I am interested in an algorithm that reaches the solved state with fewest moves.
- If describing such an algorithm is difficult, I would also be interested in the minimal number of moves required to reach an arbitrary game state from any other game state (the diameter of the game state graph).
- Calculation by @PeterLang suggests that the diameter of the game state graph is given by [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 26, 29] for the number of disks ranging from 1 to 10. There appears to be only one [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A004084) matching this pattern, and I have no clue if it should generalize.

---

Here is an example of solving the game with $3$ disks:

Given an initial state $([2], [1], [3])$, one can reach the solved state as follows:

```
                                      1        
           2         2      2         2     
2 1 3      1 3     3 1      3 1       3    
* * * => * * *  => * * * => * * * =>  * * *
```

with associated sequence of moves $[1 \to 2], [3\to 1], [2 \to 1], [2 \to 1]$.

---

I computed a graph $G$ with vertices corresponding to game states, so that an edge is drawn between two game states whenever one can be reached from another with a single legal move. Here is an example with two disks:

[image]

Surprisingly, the graph diameter seems to grow slowly. I wonder if it is always possible to reach the solved state in at most $1 + 3n$ moves, where $n$ is the number of disks (Peter's answer disproves this).

```
                 Graph Diameter  Number of Vertices
Number of Disks                                    
1                             1                   3
2                             4                  12
3                             7                  60
4                            10                 360
5                            13                2520
```

Comment: Is a solved state "all on a particular column in order" or "all on any single column in order" or something else?

Comment: An upper bound come from the triangle numbers $\frac12n(n+1)$ with the algorithm "start targeting the largest, move anything smaller not below it out of the way, move the largest to the desired column, retarget on the next largest" but you can probably do better by optimising "move anything smaller not below it out of the way"

Comment: @Henry That assumes that the largest is not already in the desired column (but not at the bottom). For subsequent discs you can assume that, but not for the first one you solve.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - that is a fair point.  I think that could add $1$ to the first phase and so to the upper bound, though it gives more scope for early optimisation of the later steps.  It does mean you could need $4$ steps for two disks

Comment: @Henry: I thought there was a particular peg that the tower had to be moved to. It says "a solved state" in the question, so it seems that the tower can be placed on any of the pegs. So you were right anyway.

Comment: @Henry I edited the question so that there is only one solved state (with all disks on peg one in order).

Comment: I calculated up to n=8 by computer, and they all had diameter 3n-2, with one of the antipodal positions being the reversed tower on peg 1. This can easily be solved in 3n-2 moves by reversing the tower from peg 1 to peg 2, then from peg 2 to peg 3, and then from 3 back to 1, and you can shave off two moves by combining the last move of one reversal with the first move of the next. It is not clear to me if this pattern continues as it might be that for larger n the diameter is larger than 3n-2. To prove it you'd have to find a solving method for arbitrary positions of 3n-2 moves max.

Comment: The pattern does not continue. For n=9 the tower 325476981 (bottom to top) on peg B or C takes 26 moves to solve.

Comment: By doing a binary [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) you can solve any position in at most $n + 2n \lceil \lg{n} \rceil$ moves. First put all the discs on the destination peg. Then do $\lceil \lg{n} \rceil$ sorting rounds, each time distributing them over the other two pegs depending on whether a particular bit of the disc's number is 0 or 1, and then transferring the 1-tower back onto the destination peg and then the 0-tower on top of that. The first round splits them according to the least significant bit, the last round on the most significant bit.

Comment: It seems to me that @JaapScherphuis Radix Sort can be improved to $\tfrac{3}{2} n \log_2 n+O(n)$. After each sort, take whichever of the two piles is smaller and put it on top of the larger one. This makes each sort cost $\tfrac{3}{2} n$ moves instead of $2n$ (plus $O(n)$ steps to clean up at the end, if we happen to end on the wrong peg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Lang says, the number of states in the graph is $(n+2)!/2$. From each state, there are at most $6$ possible moves. So the diameter of the graph is at least
$$\log_6 \frac{(n+2)!}{2} = n \frac{\log n}{\log 6} + O(n).$$

On the other hand, Jaap Scherphuis's really clever Radix Sort argument (see comment thread above) shows that the diameter is at most
$$n+2 n \lceil \log_2 n \rceil = 2 n \frac{\log n}{\log 2} + O(n).$$

Thus, I would suggest focusing our efforts on finding the constant $c$ such that the diameter grows like $c n \log n$.

---

I can improve the lower bound a little bit. It never makes sense to move a disc from peg A to peg B and then move it back, nor is it ever a good idea to move a peg from A to B and then move it from B to C (because we could have just done that in one step, A to C). So, while we have $6$ choices for the first move, we only have $4$ reasonable choices for the moves after that. This improves the lower bond to
$$1+\log_4 \frac{(n+2)!}{12} = n \frac{\log n}{\log 4} + O(n).$$

---

I can also improve the upper bound, by using a variant of merge sort rather than radix sort. Let $F(n)$ be the largest number of steps to get from any position where all discs are on one peg to the position where the discs are sorted on another peg. Let $G(n)$ be the same, except that I ask for the discs to end on the same peg they started on. Since we can always use $n$ steps at the start to stack all our discs up, the diameter of the graph is $F(n) + O(n) = G(n) + O(n)$.

Now, start with all the discs on peg 1 (in some order). Using $F(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ steps, take the top $n/2$ discs and put them, in upside down order, on peg 2, leaving the bottom $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ discs alone. Then take the discs that remain on peg 1 and move them to peg 3 in upside down order, leaving the discs which were moved earlier alone. Finally, merge both stacks back into peg 1, using $n$ steps. This shows
$$G(n) \leq F(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + F(\lceil n/2 \rfloor) + n.$$
Similarly, we have
$$F(n) \leq F(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + G(\lceil n/2 \rfloor) + n.$$
(This time, move half the pegs from 1 to 3 while sorting them, leave the others in place on 1 while sorting them, then merge unto 2.)

I believe this inductively gives us $F(n)$ and $G(n) \leq n \frac{\log n}{\log 2} + O(n)$.

---

There is still a factor of $2$ difference between $\tfrac{1}{\log 4}= \tfrac{1}{2 \log 2}$ and $\tfrac{1}{\log 2}$. Let's see if we can shrink it!

Comment: Very nice. The Radix sort can probably indeed be improved from a factor $2$ to factor $3/2$, but it is not entirely trivial. Moving a pile involves reversing its order. In the original version everything was reversed twice in each sorting round (once while separating into two piles, once when moving the resulting piles back) so no net reversal occurred. If you only move one of the two piles, this messes up the sorting order. But I think it can be fixed if you renumber the discs to take the reversals into account before sorting, cause you know which discs will be in the reversed piles.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes, I agree. But it seems like we can just keep track of whether our piles are rightside up or upside down in the current stage, and add $O(n)$ steps at the end if we have the wrong parity.

Comment: When you combine the two separated piles back into one with $n/2$ moves, you get a pile with only the top half reversed. If you then split that in the next round, you get two piles, each with their bottom section (not necessarily half) reversed. It is not simply that the pile as a whole might be upside down.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Good point. Okay, I'm not sure then.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it works out, cause as I said you can determine beforehand which discs will be in the reversed pile at each stage, and renumber them appropriately. I would not be surprised if you end up with a Gray code numbering of the discs. With this method you can also start and end on peg of your choice, so need at most $2n/3$ moves to gather everything up into one pile at the start.

Comment: I'm not going to think about it more because I found something better : Copying merge sort instead of radix sort gets me down to a factor of $1$ (instead of $2$ or $3/2$).

Answer (score 4):

For $N$ disks the state-space consists of $\frac{(N+2)!}{2!}$ vertices.

These are the results from exhaustive search:

| Disks | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Diameter | 1 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 13 | 16 | 19 | 22 | 26 | 29 |

This disproves the assumption of Diameter: $3N-2$

Examples of states which would require more steps to solve:

N=9, Steps=26, State: 3rd peg: 0 7 8 5 6 3 4 1 2

N=10, Steps=29, State: 3rd peg: 0 8 7 9 5 6 3 4 1 2

(In this representation, the desired end-state is: 1st peg: 0 1 2 ...)

The results were produced by the following code. It walks through the state-space in a Breadth-First Search manner, from the desired state, thus computes the minimal number of steps required to reach the desired state from all other states:

```
#include <deque>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

#ifndef DISKS
#define DISKS 1
#endif

const int Size = DISKS;
const int ArraySize = Size + 2;
typedef std::array<char, ArraySize> Hanoi;
// representation:
// 0. peg starts at: array[2]
// 1. peg starts at: array[array[0]]
// 2. peg starts at: array[array[1]]

Hanoi init() {
  Hanoi result;
  result[0] = ArraySize;
  result[1] = ArraySize;
  for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    result[2+i] = i;
  }
  return result;
}

Hanoi move_0_1(const Hanoi& h) {
  Hanoi result;
  int idx = 2;
  result[0] = h[0]-1;
  result[1] = h[1];
  for (int i = 2; i < h[0]-1; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  for (int i = h[0]; i < h[1]; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  result[idx++] = h[h[0]-1];
  for (int i = h[1]; i < ArraySize; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  return result;
}

Hanoi move_0_2(const Hanoi& h) {
  Hanoi result;
  int idx = 2;
  result[0] = h[0]-1;
  result[1] = h[1]-1;
  for (int i = 2; i < h[0]-1; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  for (int i = h[0]; i < h[1]; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  for (int i = h[1]; i < ArraySize; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  result[idx++] = h[h[0]-1];
  return result;
}

Hanoi move_1_0(const Hanoi& h) {
  Hanoi result;
  int idx = 2;
  result[0] = h[0]+1;
  result[1] = h[1];
  for (int i = 2; i < h[0]; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  result[idx++] = h[h[1]-1];
  for (int i = h[0]; i < h[1]-1; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  for (int i = h[1]; i < ArraySize; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  return result;
}

Hanoi move_1_2(const Hanoi& h) {
  Hanoi result;
  int idx = 2;
  result[0] = h[0];
  result[1] = h[1]-1;
  for (int i = 2; i < h[0]; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  for (int i = h[0]; i < h[1]-1; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  for (int i = h[1]; i < ArraySize; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  result[idx++] = h[h[1]-1];
  return result;
}

Hanoi move_2_0(const Hanoi& h) {
  Hanoi result;
  int idx = 2;
  result[0] = h[0]+1;
  result[1] = h[1]+1;
  for (int i = 2; i < h[0]; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  result[idx++] = h[ArraySize-1];
  for (int i = h[0]; i < h[1]; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  for (int i = h[1]; i < ArraySize-1; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  return result;
}

Hanoi move_2_1(const Hanoi& h) {
  Hanoi result;
  int idx = 2;
  result[0] = h[0];
  result[1] = h[1]+1;
  for (int i = 2; i < h[0]; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  for (int i = h[0]; i < h[1]; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  result[idx++] = h[ArraySize-1];
  for (int i = h[1]; i < ArraySize-1; i++) {
    result[idx++] = h[i];
  }
  return result;
}


std::pair<Hanoi, int> bfs_path() {
  std::pair<Hanoi, int> result = std::make_pair(init(), 0);
  std::set<Hanoi> states;
  std::deque<std::pair<Hanoi, int>> queue;
  queue.push_back(std::make_pair(init(), 0));
  while (!queue.empty()) {
    auto current = queue.front().first;
    auto path_len = queue.front().second;
    if (path_len > result.second) {
      result = queue.front();
    }
    queue.pop_front();
    Hanoi state;
    if (current[0] > 2) {
      state = move_0_1(current);
      if (states.insert(state).second) {
        queue.push_back(std::make_pair(state, path_len+1));
      }
      state = move_0_2(current);
      if (states.insert(state).second) {
        queue.push_back(std::make_pair(state, path_len+1));
      }
    }
    if (current[1] > current[0]) {
      state = move_1_0(current);
      if (states.insert(state).second) {
        queue.push_back(std::make_pair(state, path_len+1));
      }
      state = move_1_2(current);
      if (states.insert(state).second) {
        queue.push_back(std::make_pair(state, path_len+1));
      }
    }
    if (ArraySize > current[1]) {
      state = move_2_0(current);
      if (states.insert(state).second) {
        queue.push_back(std::make_pair(state, path_len+1));
      }
      state = move_2_1(current);
      if (states.insert(state).second) {
        queue.push_back(std::make_pair(state, path_len+1));
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Visited states: " << states.size() << std::endl;
  return result;
}

std::string to_string(const Hanoi& h) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  for (int i = 2; i < h[0]; i++) {
    ss << (int)h[i] << " ";
  }
  ss <<  "| ";
  for (int i = h[0]; i < h[1]; i++) {
    ss << (int)h[i] << " ";
  }
  ss <<  "| ";
  for (int i = h[1]; i < ArraySize; i++) {
    ss << (int)h[i] << " ";
  }
  return ss.str();
}

int main() {
  auto result = bfs_path();
  std::cout << "Max steps needed: " << result.second << " For State: " << to_string(result.first) << std::endl;
}
```

It is recommended to compile it with the best optimization, e.g.:

`g++ hanoi.cpp -D DISKS=8 -std=c++11 -O3 -o hanoi && ./hanoi`